# Connecting to specific nodes in a Hadoop distributed system

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, distributed-computing, apache-zookeeper

I am running a Hadoop distributed system with a master node and some worker nodes. The worker nodes need to be able to handle various requests sent from clients on a web app, but only some of the worker nodes are able to handle certain requests since only some of them have processes open to handle these requests. I can't have copies of these processes running on all nodes due to memory constraints and I can't open new processes on the fly since they take too long to start. I need to design a system so that requests get routed to the appropriate worker nodes with the matching processes.

I think it would be possible to use the master node to track information about the running processes on the worker nodes and route all incoming requests based on that information. Are there any Hadoop related systems that can accomplish this task? I would strongly prefer to use something like ZooKeeper or MapReduce but I am not sure if these systems are capable of targeting specific nodes in a cluster. If none of the Hadoop related systems are suitable for this task, are there any other good options (perhaps using sockets to communicate between the master and worker nodes)?

Comment: Why do you need/want to use Hadoop for this task?

Comment: As far as I know, mainly for HDFS currently. We need our nodes to synchronize and share files. Also our servers are already configured to use Hadoop and it wouldn't be easy for me to change that. I want to know if any of the Hadoop related systems would be useful for completing this task, and if not, what are some other options?

Comment: When you say requests, do you mean HTTP requests? In this case you can probably can use apache (mod_proxy) or ngnix to achieve what you want.

Comment: Currently the worker nodes do not run Apache or any HTTP servers. I originally intended on sending raw data to the nodes (ex: a string) and then when the processes on the nodes are done with their computations, the nodes would return something else (ex: a status int/byte). Running Apache servers on the worker nodes seems like a viable alternative if I can directly route the requests from the web app. Thanks for the suggestions.